# Custom bootstrap 4 breadcrumbs arrow effect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to modify the **bootstrap 4** breadcrumbs in stead of this `/` divider I would like `>` look like but all the way to edge Just like in this image

[image]

> Question How can I make my breadcrumbs show full arrow at end of link like image above.

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/zdJdOd)

My CSS

```
.breadcrumb {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd !important;
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
}

.breadcrumb::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}

.breadcrumb-item {
    float: left;
}

.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 32px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 32px solid transparent;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
}

.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item:hover::before {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item:hover::before {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.breadcrumb-item.active {
    color: #868e96;
}
```

HTML

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It's better to create another breadcrumb than modifying bootstrap breadcrumb, you'll need to override much css

Comment: Thanks will keep that in mind.

Comment: https://codepen.io/firatcftc/pen/sHlnK

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/triangle-breadcrumbs-arrows

Comment: These are all non-bootstrap 4 examples. Any examples with bootstrap 4?