# Nav menu appearing wrong with Bootstrap 4 vs 3.3.7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am using the attached CSS and code and the height of my `<li>` are getting screwed up. It's too short when using bootstrap 4, but it works in 3.3.7. What is the issue when working with 4"?

#### Does Bootstrap 4 have a good way of doing this? What's the best way to accomplish this?

There is another questions here:
[Custom bootstrap 4 breadcrumbs arrow effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894429/custom-bootstrap-4-breadcrumbs-arrow-effect)

Without an answer.

I have found multiple examples in Bootstrap 3, not but 4. Any examples would be appreciated.

Example 1:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/44am

Example 2:
Version 3.3.7
https://jsfiddle.net/vjstg2zc/1/

Version 4
https://jsfiddle.net/cpLd4u5e/

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-wizard">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li + li {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li a {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li:not(:last-child) a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0px;
  right: -20px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #eee;
  z-index: 150;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li:not(:first-child) a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  border-color: #eee #eee #eee transparent;
  z-index: 150;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li:hover:not(:last-child) a:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #aaa;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li:hover:not(:first-child) a:before {
  border-color: #aaa #aaa #aaa transparent;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li:hover a {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li.active:not(:last-child) a:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #428bca;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li.active:not(:first-child) a:before {
  border-color: #428bca #428bca #428bca transparent;
}
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li.active a {
  background-color: #428bca;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *bootstrap3* to *bootstrap4*, beside its primary CSS unit has been changed from `px` to `rem`, the *navs* component has been completely rewritten using *flexbox* with simpler structure.

In *bootstrap3*, it has default style for the *navs*:

```css
.nav > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
```

In fact, if you add `position: relative;` and `display: block;` in your *bootstrap4* sample, it kind of worked too: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ka83uLq6/4/:

```css
.nav-pills.nav-wizard > li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
    ...
}
```

In *bootstrap4*, `nav-link` class is added for similar purpose, and you don't have to build the *navs* using list. The reason why you saw in *bootstrap4* that the height was not right simply because there is no nested structure like `.nav > li > a` anymore.

Since you've asked the best way to do it in *bootstrap4*, let me see if I can craft out what you have in *bootstrap4*.

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/5xod17mw/41/

[image]

If you're using *SASS/SCSS*, there is so much more you can clean up in your style as you can define variables for border color, etc, and define mixins as function to set the right border(s) to the right color.

#### Center it on the page

Since `.nav` is already displayed as *flexbox*. You can easily center its item by adding `.justify-content-center` on the `.nav`:

```html
<div class="container">
    <nav class="nav nav-pills nav-wizard justify-content-center">
        ...
    </nav>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/5xod17mw/51/

[image]

Comment: Any advice to make this responsive too?

Comment: Explain what responsiveness you're thinking? To me it's already responsive as it will wrap around on smaller screens, but of course there are lots of room for improvement, to make it even prettier.

Comment: I've added a demo on how to center it on the page. Regarding to the responsiveness, I will leave that one to you. I've felt like I'm giving out too much here :)

Comment: adding  margin-bottom: 1rem; gave the breadcrumbs a nice look and looks great on a responsive website too. thank you. https://jsfiddle.net/n0yjap8c/